# TestNG Factory to Run Test Classes Sequntially

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have a TestNG @Factory Class, a Base class which creates the drivers and two test class that contain multiple @Test methods to run the tests. Given my @Factory class below.

```html
public class SampleFactory {

    @Factory(dataProvider="DeviceDetails")
    public synchronized Object[] factoryMethod(String deviceID){
     return new Object[] {new IndTest(deviceID),new IndTestTwo(deviceID)};
    }


    @DataProvider(name="DeviceDetails",parallel=true)
    public Object[][] passDeviceID(){
     return new Object[][] {{"02157DF2DA5A1C09"},{"D5588B67"}};
    }
}
```

`IndTest` and `IndTest2` are the two test classes. They extend the Base Class and call the Base class constructor to create the drivers. Only one instance of the driver can be used at a particular time for a particular deviceID.

The problem I am facing is that both IndTest and IndTest2 are being run at the same time the tests try to run different tests on particular device at the same time. I require the IndTest class to be called first and run the tests inside that class on device 1 and device 2 and then move to IndTest2 and carry out the same sort of execution. Below is the TestNG xml that I use currently.

```html
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test_Suite" skipfailedinvocationcounts="false" junit="false" parallel="classes"
data-provider-thread-count="100" annotations="JDK" group-by-instances="true"/>
```

Awaiting your ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to tweak the TestNG.xml a little bit. Give the following a shot

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Test_Suite" > 
    <test name="something">
        <classes>
            <class name="something.IndTest" />
            <class name="something.IndTest2" />
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

However, test dependencies are often consider as bad practice. All the tests should be independent so that they can provide you intelligent feedback without depending on the order of execution.

Comment: I tried this already and there is no change. In fact, the tests doesn't have any dependency on each other. The problem is the driver, or the mobile device on which I need to run the tests. I can only run one test at a time on a particular time, it results in a failure when two tests (two drivers created from each test) try to use the same device at the same time.